# Get the views field value

Tags: views, 8, theming

How to get the views field value and make a condition base on that field. Let say may views field is 'field_state'

Example below:

```
function my_module_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  //current user id
  $user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  //load user data
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user_id);
   // Get user state
  $state = $user->get('field_state')->getValue()[0]['value'];  
  if ($state == Views field_state value) {
        $view->field['field_state']->options['exclude'] = TRUE; // exclude field for only this result ???
  }
  else{
    $view->field['field_state']->options['exclude'] = FALSE; // include field for only this result ??? 
  }
}
```

Is it possible on views pre-render or I need to use the different hook?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `hook_views_post_build()`. I haven't tried this but I was looking at the [views api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/8.2.x) and noticed that [hook_views_post_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_build/8.5.x) shows an example of modifying the `exclude` property of a field.